# Subtract columns from DataFrames with different shapes by looking up based on another column

Tags: pandas

`df2` has more columns and rows than `df1`. For each row in `df2`, I want to lookup a corresponding row in `df1` based on matching values in one of their columns. From this matching row in `df1`, I want to subtract a column between `df2` and `df1`. I tried `set_index` and directly subtracting the dataframes, but that resulted in a lot of `NaN`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]],
                   columns=['A', 'B'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 100, 15], [1, 200, 20],
                    [2, 100, 30], [2, 200, 35],
                    [3, 100, 50], [3, 200, 55]],
                   columns=['A', 'X', 'B'])

# For each row in df2, lookup in df1 based on column A, and produce
# difference of values in columnn B.  
expected = pd.DataFrame([[1, 100, 5], [1, 200, 10],
                        [2, 100, 10], [2, 200, 15],
                        [3, 100, 20], [3, 200, 25]],
                       columns=['A', 'X', 'B'])
```

DataFrames:

```
df1
   A   B
0  1  10
1  2  20
2  3  30

df2
   A    X   B
0  1  100  15
1  1  200  20
2  2  100  30
3  2  200  35
4  3  100  50
5  3  200  55

expected
   A    X   B
0  1  100   5
1  1  200  10
2  2  100  10
3  2  200  15
4  3  100  20
5  3  200  25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` also:

```
df2.merge(df1, on='A').eval('B = B_x - B_y').drop(['B_x','B_y'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A    X   B
0  1  100   5
1  1  200  10
2  2  100  10
3  2  200  15
4  3  100  20
5  3  200  25
```

Comment: Nice one on `eval` +1

Comment: @AndyL.  Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3):

set_index `df1` to 'A' and map it back to `df2.A`. After that do subtraction:

```
df2['B'] -= df2.A.map(df1.set_index('A').B)

Out[216]:
   A    X   B
0  1  100   5
1  1  200  10
2  2  100  10
3  2  200  15
4  3  100  20
5  3  200  25
```

**Note**: In case `df2.A` has values doesn't exist in `df1.A`, it will return `NaN` on that row. I leave it that way because your sample data doesn't specify how to handle it. If you want to keep the value of `B` the same in that case, you just need to chain `.fillna(0)` to the end of `map` or call method `subtract` with `fill_value=0` option

```
df2['B'] -= df2.A.map(df1.set_index('A').B).fillna(0)
```

Comment: I like this use of `map` here.  Nice.  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston: Thank you :)